# closing a modal dialog on button click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have a modal window that opens on the click of an item in dropdown.
 I got stuck in implementing the closing of dialog on a button click.

```
 var $that = this;
 $("#btncart_cancel").on("click", function () {
      ///// ***********close the dialog *************** 
      /// tried this but not working
      $that.dialog("close");
 });
```

My code :

```
$(".ddlCart li").click(function (e) {
$('#actionsCart').slideToggle();

var ddlselectedVal = $(this).attr('id');
var selectedListinsCount = selected_Listings.length;
var SelectedMlsnums = selected_Listings.join();
var agentId = $("#AgentId").val();

var EnvironmentURL = $("#EnvironmentURL").val();

var autoUrl = "/Stats/SearchContacts";
var Action = "PreAddToCart"

var postData = {
    AgentId: agentId,
    Mlsnums: SelectedMlsnums,
    ActionTypeValue: Action
};
var $that = this;
var close = function (event, ui) {
    $(this).dialog("destroy");
}
var open = function (event, ui) {
    var agentId = $("#AgentId").val();
    var url = EnvironmentURL + "/Stats/SearchContacts";

    $("#btncart_cancel").on("click", function () {
        ///// ***********close the dialog *************** 
    });

    $("#btncart_submit").on("click", function () {
        $(".liloading").show();

        if (App.ContactInfo.Id != 'undefined') {
            var contactKey = App.ContactInfo.Id;
            var cartName = App.ContactInfo.Name;
        } else {
            var contactKey = 0;
            var cartName = 'My Personal Cart';
        }

        var note = $("#txtNotes").val();
        var url = EnvironmentURL + "/Stats/Cart";

        //Send the data using post and put the results in a div                   
        $.post(url, {
            CartName: cartName,
            Notes: note,
            Contactkey: contactKey,
            ActionTypeValue: "AddToCart"
        },

        function (data) {
            // Replace current data with data from the ajax call to the div.         
            $("#dvModalDialog").empty().append(data);

        });
    });
};

var rd = Mod.ReportsDialog({
    title: 'Add To Cart',
    close: close,
    open: open
});
rd.url = EnvironmentURL + "/Stats/Cart";
rd.targetElement = '#dvModalDialog' // '#dvSendEmail'
rd.formName = '#frmCart'
rd.postData = postData
rd.open();
var $that = this;
});
```

Comment: your problem might be for having nested `click` events

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem that I see with your close method is that the `$that` is not a JQuery object.

You could probably fix this with either `$($that).dialog("close")` or `$(this).dialog("close")` or `$('#dvModalDialog').dialog("close")`.

Answer (score 4):

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#modalClose').click(function (){
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                  $('#contact').modal('hide');
                }, 5000);
              });
          });
```

for `Button` use `id = modalClose` and for modal use `id = contact`